# PHP List all instead of 1

Tags: php

I have this code which *should* show all the `$scheme` values in a `<ul>`. As you can see below, I have 2 `$scheme` variables, but only 1 shows up in the `<ul>`.

```
$scheme = colorscheme('Test', 'hello');
$scheme = colorscheme('Black', 'hello');

function colorscheme( $color, $url ) {
    return array( $color, $url );
}

echo '<ul>';
foreach ($scheme as $value) {
    echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

How can I make it so every `$scheme` shows up instead of only 1?

Comment: I recognise your function from another question yesterday. I urge you to study PHP basics a bit more, as you don't seem to fully understand how simple things like variables and arrays work. That is like one of the first things you should understand before continuing with programming. Again, your function is also pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As you can see below, I have 2 `$scheme` variables, but **only 1 shows up** in the `<ul>`.

That's because `$scheme` variable gets overwritten with each function call. See here,

```
$scheme = colorscheme('Test', 'hello');  // Here, $scheme = array('Test', 'hello');
$scheme = colorscheme('Black', 'hello'); // Here, $scheme = array('Black', 'hello');
```

> How can I make it so every `$scheme` shows up instead of only 1?

Make `$scheme` as an array, and append the returned array, from `colorscheme()` function, to this array, like this:

```
$scheme = array();
$scheme[] = colorscheme('Test', 'hello');
$scheme[] = colorscheme('Black', 'hello');
```

And then loop through this `$scheme` array using `foreach` loop to display all color schemes.

```
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($scheme as $colorscheme) {
    foreach($colorscheme as $value){
        echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>';
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out here Rajdeep!

Comment: How can I call a specific value, such as the first or second value?

Comment: @Jerrald Could you please explain what do you mean by *first or second value*? What's your expected output?

Comment: `$scheme[] = colorscheme('Test', 'hello');`, like the first output 'Test' and the second one 'hello'. How can I call them in the foreach?

Comment: @Jerrald You mean kinda like this, [http://pastebin.com/m9NRZtAG](http://pastebin.com/m9NRZtAG)? Inside outer `foreach` loop, you can access first value as `$colorscheme[0]` and second value as `$colorscheme[1]`.

Comment: Yes, that's it! :)

Answer (score 0):

By using the same variable name twice, you're just overwriting it on the second line. You need to use unique variable names for each scheme, or hold them all in an array (which would be preferable).

Also, your function serves no purpose whatsoever and is redundant.

In simple terms you could put all the schemes into a multi-dimensional array, which is an array comprised of sub-arrays. Then loop through the main array and retrieve the two elements of each sub-array so you can echo them.

```
$schemes = array(
    array('White', 'scheme 1'),
    array('Black', 'scheme 2'),
    array('Green', 'scheme 3')
);

echo '<ul>';
foreach ($schemes as $scheme) {
    $color = $scheme[0];
    $url = $scheme[1];
    echo "<li>$color = $url</li>";
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: This will not work for me as the array (`$schemes`) is called by the user. This will conflict when multiple users are calling the `$schemes`.

Comment: @Jerrald Sorry, what you're saying doesn't make much sense. Perhaps what you're actually trying to achieve requires you to implement this code in a certain way, but the code logic itself is very basic and will work. What do you mean by the user calling the array, or multiple users?

Comment: Any user. Like WordPress, they can call custom color schemes from anywhere if they like in their plugins and it will add up to the color scheme section of WordPress. I'm trying to archieve the same effect.